# Show tooltip on keypress for anchor tag using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

can i know how to show a tooltip during keypress on an anchor tag using Jquery ?

```
<a id="resultToolTip" href="#" data-tooltip="" class="has-tip"
title="User: Test Passed">Test Results</a>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#resultToolTip').keypress(function(){

  });
</script>
```

Comment: How exactly do you input text and trigger key events on an anchor ?

Comment: Afaik, you can't use the title-attribute like it is normally used with hovering over the anshor tag.

Comment: I too am having trouble with this. it worked beforeI moved from JQuery 1.6 to 1.9, but keyup/down/press isn't working all round for me anymore. I used up down arrows extensively for page navigation by keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to press a key on a link? That doesn't make any sense. I would bind to the hover event.

Comment: By using tab (or other keyboard shortcuts) to focus on the link (or other element), then pressing a key

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous, do you mean the tooltip open only whilst a key is pressed and held?
Perhaps any key when focussed anywhere anywhere on the page will show all the tooltips that are available?
Do you want it to react only to a specific key?

Here's the simplest solution that I managed to get working adapted to your code. If you have multiple instances and want it to react differently I can write up something more specific.

JQuery 1.9.

```
<a id="resultToolTip" href="#" data-tooltip="" class="has-tip"
title="User: Test Passed">Test Results</a>
<div id="my-tooltip-div">This is the tooltip</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("keypress", "#resultToolTip", function() {
      // show my tooltip
      // e.g. $("#my-tooltip-div").fadeIn('fast');
      // if #my-tooltip-div is the tooltip you want to show
    });
  });
</script>
```

The anchor link has to be focused upon first by means of tabbing to it or using some sort of jquery focusing after another event/trigger.